# Generate Lat / Lon from addresses in mySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, google-maps, latitude-longitude

I currently have a mySQL table of addresses of certain locations that I need to obtain Latitude and Longitude for.  This is a table being used in WordPress to map store locations to google maps.  I am looking for the best way to obtain the lat/lon for all of the records in this database.

Does anyone know a simple strategy I could use to run through all of the records and obtain the lat/lon of each address?

Comment: Title says "XLS file", question says mysql table/database?

Comment: Take a look at the JavaScript source of [GetLanLon.com](http://www.getlatlon.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google have the Geocoding API - http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/

Comment: Yup, either Google or [Yahoo's](http://developer.yahoo.com/maps/rest/V1/geocode.html) geocoding APIs are probably the way to go if you need to turn a physical address into a location.

Comment: Thanks for this, any idea on best practice for running through the database and update entries. pardon my noobness this is my first time doing something of this sort.

Comment: Of course I don't know how many entries you will be updating per day (2500 limit per day with Google Geocoding) however if it's regular then you can set up a cron job or just have it call when you save the address. Add a latitude and longitude field to your database (set them to be double rather than float as float doesn't hold enough). Then run a query to get all the rows which have no latitude and longitude. Perform a request on each of these (from a quick look I couldn't see that the API allows you to send an array so you'll have to do each one). Parse the result and update the fields.

Comment: Just for the record I have picked a lot more then 2500 lat/lng pairs a day but I'm living in Europe and also nobody is voting for me!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what kind of addresses you mean. If IP then there are databases that will give you the approx lat and long for most of your visitor's IPs. You will have to capture it then.

If you mean postal addresses then, I know of nothing to help world wide. In the UK, the Royal Mail's PAF used to contain lat and long, but you must have the post code. I suspect there might be similar data available for ZIP codes in the US and Cedex codes in France.

Other than that, I expect you will be out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking for code? I use a bash script to solve it. It's not a copy actually it is quite simple with Linux bash commandl-ine. Most likely you want to dump your database into a text file and then read and query it from them shell. It took me about 4-5 hours for a country like Germany with postcode from 0-99999.